# Интеграционное тестирование API

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, api, тестирование

Есть в упрощенном виде на сервере такие endpoints:

```
GET /users
POST /users — создание пользователя
GET /users/{id}
DELETE /users/{id}
```

Сервер и клиент на одном и том же сервере.
База для тестирования sqlite у них общая.
Допустим, для каждого endpoint у меня тест. 
В каждом тесте отправляется http запрос на endpoint с помощью http-клиента, как если бы это делал клиент (consumer), и проверяется ответ на корректность. 
Перед самым началом тестов создается пустая БД и накатывается миграция. После тестов база удаляется.

Моя проблема в том, что перед каждым тестом нужно создавать 7 пользователей с фейковыми данными. И после теста чтобы они "удалялись". И на следующем тесте опять эта же цепочка создание-удаление.

1. Сначала делал через транзакции БД, то есть тест начинается и запускается на клиенте транзакция, создаются 7 пользователей, в тесте идет http запрос на GET /users но на сервере же транзакции нет и пустая БД. Поэтому этот вариант отпадает.
2. Если делать без транзакции то на клиенте и сервере за счет того что общая БД данные одинаковые, но мне нужно чтобы перед каждым тестом было только 7 пользователей, чтобы предыдущие манипуляции с БД не коверкали данные. Поэтому этот вариант тоже отпадает.
3. Попробовал вариант где делается удаление БД и миграция перед каждым тестом. Работает но очень долго (минута нужна чтобы проверить 4 endpoints). In memory БД тут бы ускорила сильно, но тут та же проблема как при транзакции.

Никак не могу найти решение. Что можете посоветовать?
Хочу протестировать все endpoints именно не через функциональные тесты внутри кода, а как бы извне (как интерфейс тестируют через selenium).

Answer (score 1):

В аналогичной ситуации в одном проекте перед началом тестов создаётся отдельная тестовая БД, в неё копируется структура боевой БД и заполняется фейковыми данными. Для одного теста, или для группы тестов. Затем удаляется.

Тесты используют mock объекта для работы с БД, где вместо боевой подставляется тестовая БД.

Иногда нужно прогнать недеструктивные тесты над существующими записями в боевой или стейджовой БД; или не удобно обновлять тестовые данные – можно переключать используемую базу.

Comment: Мой вопрос, собственно, в прогоне недеструктивных и **деструктивных** тестов в случае если запросы идут по http и нет возможности сделать транзакции т.к. http является stateless.

Comment: Для тестов используется отдельная копия проекта и свой уникальный ip:port, куда больше никто не стучится.